# unsatisfied forward or external declaration for procedure

Tags: delphi, procedure

My program wont compile because it says that my procedure has an unsatisfied forward or external declaration... I actually have no idea what that means...

```
private 
  procedure ShowData;

implementation

procedure ShowData;
var 
  Cycle2UFile : textfile;
  Str : String;
  J, 
  Count : integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  AssignFile( Cycle2UFile, 'data.txt' );
  Reset( Cycle2UFile );
  While not EOF( Cycle2UFile ) do
    begin
      Inc( Count );
      ReadLn( Cycle2UFile , ArrNames[Count] );
      ReadLn( Cycle2UFile, ArrSales[Count] );
    end;
  CloseFile( Cycle2UFile );
  // Randomize; 
end;
```

I cant see any problems with this.

Comment: `private` is only known inside a class definition but never standalone. So just remove `private` or embed your code inside a class definition as @TLama wrote in his answer

Comment: Just as a note: You should avoid variable names starting with `T` because every delphi programmer would expect that to be a class ;o)

Comment: I just edited your code to get the variable names more "speakable" and removed that `Randomize`, because this should not be called more than once in an application. (best place for that is at the beginning of the `.dpr` file)

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please ask a new question on the other problem that arose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your code **compiling** just remove that `private`.

`private` is a delphi keyword and is only known inside a class definition but makes no sense using standalone.

```
// private 
  procedure ShowData;

implementation

procedure ShowData;
var 
  Cycle2UFile : textfile;
  Str : String;
  J, 
  Count : integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  AssignFile( Cycle2UFile, 'data.txt' );
  Reset( Cycle2UFile );
  While not EOF( Cycle2UFile ) do
    begin
      Inc( Count );
      ReadLn( Cycle2UFile , ArrNames[Count] );
      ReadLn( Cycle2UFile, ArrSales[Count] );
    end;
  CloseFile( Cycle2UFile );
  // Randomize; 
end;
```